# How can I disable Lucene.Net query parser regular expressions

Tags: lucene.net

I would like to disable the query parser regular expression feature so that forward slashes will be considered as normal characters without having to be escaped. Is this possible out of the box? If not, how would I create such a query parser?

Comment: I'm curious, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No (had 13 more characters to type)